# Ubuntu Touch: How can I debug ubuntu touch apps on the device?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml

My app works well on desktop but I can't figure out why does it crash on my nexus 7.
How can I debug it while it runs on the device?

Comment: How is this different this from your last post?

Comment: @Seth: Viewing outputs from an application is very different from running it inside a debugger. So IMHO both questions are perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to make your system partition writable by doing [1](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg04004.html):

```
touch /userdata/.writable_image
```

and rebooting your phone/tablet. Be aware that you cannot install over-the-air (OTA) updates after doing this. Then you need to install gdb:

```
apt-get install gdb
```

Finally, when launching the app from Qt Creator like shown [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBpCykbmqs8), instead of pressing the "Run" button, press the "Debug" button below. It should then launch the app through gdbserver and show the debugging interface in Qt Creator.

That's the theory. However I didn't get it running. Qt Creator spits out various error dialogs, some saying "Unknown Error", others having no text at all. I'm currently trying to run my application from the command line on my Nexus 4, which is incredibly difficult.